# How to display dynamic button in codeigniter using Gd library?

Tags: image, codeigniter, gdlib

I created form with dynamic color,font,size of button .
   when i submit the form, button image displaying in full page,i need to display in first page itself.

my controller code :

```
public function creatorbuton(){
    $button_size = $this->input->POST('button_size');
    $font_style = $this->input->POST('font_style');
    $color_schme = $this->input->POST('color_schme');
    $textdisplay = $this->input->POST('textdisplay');
    header('content-type: image/png');

    //Create our basic image stream 
    //125px width, 125px height
    $image = imagecreate(120, 60);

    //Set the background color
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 50, 105);

    //Set up another color just to show how the first color declared is used as the background color when we use imagecreate() 
    //Notice how blue is applied to the background, *not* red.
    $red = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 200, 10);

    //$font = myurl.'fonts/arial.ttf';
    //$text="Hello";
    //imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 11, 21, $red, $font, $text);
    //save the image as a png and output 
    $result_array['final_image'] = imagepng($image);

    //Clear up memory used
    imagedestroy($image);
    $this->load->view('buttonconfig/buttoncreator',$result_array);
```

How to dispaly the button in buttoncreator view page. When i used uncomment this line

```
imagettftext($image, 20, 0, 11, 21, $red, $font, $text);
```

I got  this line  " The image  MY URL   cannot be displayed baecause it contains errors" .

Comment: Please be more careful with the formatting of your code in future. You're more likely to get a positive response if your code is easy to read and understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got output : my code is

```
public function creatorparam(){ 
    $bg_color="FF8640";
    $text_color="C7FFE3";
    $button_width =120;
    $button_height =90; 

    $r_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,0,2));
    $g_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,2,2));
    $b_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,4,2));

    $r_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,0,2));
    $g_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,2,2));
    $b_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,4,2));
    header('content-type: image/png');  
    $image = imagecreate($button_width, $button_height); 
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bg, $g_bg, $b_bg); 
    $red = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bgt, $g_bgt, $b_bgt);  
    imagestring($image,18,0,0,$textdisplay,$red); 
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image); 
}
```